# Will an electrolytic capacitor work reliably with 0 VDC and 100 mVAC?

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, electrolytic-capacitor, polarity, negative

I ran across an instrumentation amplifier [datasheet](http://www.thatcorp.com/datashts/dn138.pdf) from "THAT Corporation", and noticed the polarized capacitor in series with the gain resistor:

[image]

It is a typical 3 op-amp in-amp, so the differential input will be seen across the gain resistor, and C1 is meant to avoid changes in dc output offset with gain.

Now, the input is typically a microphone, and the AC voltage can reach 100mV or even a bit more.

For a 2k gain resistor and 6.8uF cap, 10 Hz will be seen with -3dB across the cap: 70 mVAC.

So the question is, will an electrolytic survive and work properly during these small negative excursions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it appears that this is OK for such small voltages.

According to CDE's [Application Guide, Aluminum Electrolytic Capacitors](http://www.cde.com/resources/catalogs/AEappGUIDE.pdf):

> Aluminum electrolytic capacitors are polarized and must be
>   connected in the correct polarity. They can withstand
>   reverse voltages up to 1.5 V.

If you are uncomfortable with that (from the same application guide):

> If two, same-value, aluminum electrolytic capacitors
>   are connected in series, back-to-back with the positive
>   terminals or the negative terminals connected, the
>   resulting single capacitor is a non-polar capacitor with
>   half the capacitance.

For solid Tantalum capacitors, from [Vishay's Solid Tantalum Capacitors:
Frequently Asked Questions (FAQs)](http://www.vishay.com/docs/40110/faq.pdf):

> Tantalum capacitors are capable of withstanding peak voltages in the reverse direction equal to 10 % of the DC rating at
>   + 25 °C and 5 % of the DC rating at + 85 °C.

Also, you may not want to consider a ceramic capacitor for this due to the piezoelectric effects: [Ceramic vs. Film Capacitor: Which one is preferred in audio circuits?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69919/ceramic-vs-film-capacitor-which-one-is-preferred-in-audio-circuits)