# Which type of aluminum capacitor should I choose?

Tags: arduino, capacitor, surface-mount

[image]

Well generally I am confused, same values and almost same size. One of them is an SMD electrolytic and the other is a through hole electrolytic with long thin legs.

Where should I use which capacitor?

Actually I need more detail information. I would appreciate it if you could share some documents or videos.

Comment: What is your application for the capacitor?

Comment: I want to learn in general which capacitor should be chosen in which application.

Comment: [This might help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177575/capacitor-selection-for-filtering-of-low-level-signal/177580#177580). There are plenty of Q/As on this site about capacitors; use the search tool provided.

Comment: It depends a lot on, not just the application but manufacturing process and budget and environmental temperature and other things so your last line (and latest comment) make it a very broad question. A summary might be: both will work; use either.

Comment: Sometimes many capacitors are used in parallel, sometimes different types. But answering which capacitor to use in which situation depends on which properties of the capacitor is important in that specific situation, and which different properties of different types of capacitors have. This info is already available if searched. It would most likely take a few lectures or maybe a book worth of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing a PC board with surface mount parts, you would normally use surface mount electrolytic capacitors.

If you are designing a board with through-hole parts, you would use a capacitor with wire leads.

There would be no electrical reason to choose between leaded and surface mount - the choice is just based on the physical mounting style.

Comment: There are in fact very concrete electrical reasons to choose surface mount over through-hole, when HF analysis comes into play. Parasitics are characterized differently between the two.

Answer (score 1):

By some miracle I found the likely vendor you're looking at, and the [first](https://www.direnc.net/330uf-25v-kondansator-11x5) and [second](https://www.direnc.net/330uf-25v-8x10-5000hrs-105c-smd-elektrolitik-kondansator-xxx) capacitor product pages.

Your claim that these two caps have the

> same values

is, interestingly, not true for any comprehensive definition of "values". Aside from the first being through-hole and the second being surface-mount - which will significantly influence board layout decisions -

- They're rated for different lifetimes, 2000 vs. 5000 hours.
- They are from different manufacturers - Koshin vs. Samyoung, and thus from very different product lines.

Direnc unfortunately does not link to any specsheets, so there will be many other parameters - leakage, current tolerances, etc. - that differ. The first of these that I would want to compare is maximum tolerable current, which will affect any inrush analysis that you need to do.